# how can i configurate a RFID UHF sensor in android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am developing an android app for reading UHF RFID tags, I am using the Chainway C72 device, a phone that has an integrated RFID sensor, the issue is that using the SDK of the provider, I have a problem and is that I can not start the sensor because I get a communication error in the console every time I try to activate it within the application.

I attach the code I have made for testing the sensor only:

```
package com.example.pruebarfid2

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import com.rscja.deviceapi.RFIDWithUHFUART

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val rfid = RFIDWithUHFUART.getInstance()
    private var isInventory = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hola!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            uhf()
        }
    }

    private fun uhf() {
        val result = rfid.init(this)
        if (!result) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Conexión fallida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "Conexión exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        // Configuración de parámetros
        // rfid.setFrequencyMode(xx)
        // rfid.setPower(30)

        if (rfid.startInventoryTag()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Lectura iniciada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            isInventory = true
            ThreadInventory().start()
        } else {
            rfid.stopInventory()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al iniciar la lectura", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        // ..............

        rfid.stopInventory()
        isInventory = false

        // .................

        // Desconectar UHF
        rfid.free()
        Toast.makeText(this, "UHF desconectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    private inner class ThreadInventory : Thread() {
        override fun run() {
            while (isInventory) {
                val uhftagInfo = rfid.readTagFromBuffer()
                if (uhftagInfo == null) {
                    Thread.sleep(20)
                    continue
                }

                val epc = uhftagInfo.epc
                val rssi = uhftagInfo.rssi

                // .....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I leave you the error in console every time I press the button to read the tag:

````
D/DeviceAPI: [MTK] load DeviceAPIM.so
I/DeviceAPI: UHF device = C72_6765
I/DeviceAPI: UHF_Init----------->DEVICE_C72_6765
D/DeviceAPI: [mt_gpio_ioctl] platform=6765, gpio=set 165 0111000100, gpiolen=18
E/DeviceAPI: [mt_gpio_ioctl] open error: [13]: Permission denied
W/ple.pruebarfid2: type=1400 audit(0.0:1334): avc: denied { read write } for name="mt_gpio" dev="sysfs" ino=34038 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c170,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mt_gpio:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.example.pruebarfid2
W/ple.pruebarfid2: type=1400 audit(0.0:1335): avc: denied { read write } for name="mt_gpio" dev="sysfs" ino=34038 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c170,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mt_gpio:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.example.pruebarfid2
D/DeviceAPI: [mt_gpio_ioctl] platform=6765, gpio=set 158 0111000100, gpiolen=18
E/DeviceAPI: [mt_gpio_ioctl] open error: [13]: Permission denied
D/DeviceAPI: [mt_gpio_ioctl] platform=6765, gpio=set 155 0111000100, gpiolen=18
E/DeviceAPI: [mt_gpio_ioctl] open error: [13]: Permission denied
D/DeviceAPI: [mt_gpio_ioctl] platform=6765, gpio=set 165 0111000100, gpiolen=18
E/DeviceAPI: [mt_gpio_ioctl] open error: [13]: Permission denied
D/DeviceAPI: [mt_gpio_ioctl] platform=6765, gpio=set 24 0111000100, gpiolen=17
E/DeviceAPI: [mt_gpio_ioctl] open error: [13]: Permission denied
D/DeviceAPI: [mt_gpio_ioctl] platform=6765, gpio=set 21 0111000100, gpiolen=17
E/DeviceAPI: [mt_gpio_ioctl] open error: [13]: Permission denied
W/ple.pruebarfid2: type=1400 audit(0.0:1336): avc: denied { read write } for name="mt_gpio" dev="sysfs" ino=34038 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c170,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mt_gpio:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.example.pruebarfid2
I/chatty: uid=10170(com.example.pruebarfid2) identical 2 lines
W/ple.pruebarfid2: type=1400 audit(0.0:1339): avc: denied { read write } for name="mt_gpio" dev="sysfs" ino=34038 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c170,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mt_gpio:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.example.pruebarfid2
I/DeviceAPI: UHF_Init----------->DevIsOpen = 1
I/DeviceAPI: UHF_OpenAndConnect: uart = /dev/ttyS1
D/DeviceAPI_SerialPort: [SerialPort_Open] [13]: Permission denied
I/DeviceAPI: UHF uhf_uart_fd = -1
I/DeviceAPI_UHF: init() Uart = /dev/ttyS1
E/DeviceAPI_UHF: init() err UHFOpenAndConnect result:-1
W/ple.pruebarfid2: type=1400 audit(0.0:1340): avc: denied { read write } for name="ttyS1" dev="tmpfs" ino=12322 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c170,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:ttyS_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0 app=com.example.pruebarfid2```


I enable all the configuration to read/write files and usb services but nothing.
````

Comment: Hola Jose, estoy en el mismo caso. Encontraste como hacer funcionar el SDK?

Comment: Jose ojala hayas encontrado como soluicionarlo, llevo todo el dia y no puedo dar con la solucion.

Comment: Pues al finalizar no pude configurar directamente el sensor a mi app, mi dispositivo tiene una app que se llama "Keyboard emulator" que me permite utilizar el sensor como un procesador de texto en cualquier aplicación. entonces en mi app cree un cuadro de texto invisible que solo será seleccionado pulsado un botón, luego cuando presiono el botón de escanear se lee el tag RFID y se escribe el código en ese cuadro invisible, devolviéndome el resultado (en mi caso cambia valores en una hoja de excel) y funcionando como quería.